# Python3, TkInter: Box fade-out with itemconfig evidently waits time between steps, but does not shift box's color as should

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm a human trying to make an animated musical keyboard type thing so keystrokes play noises and flash pretty colors on screen that make ape brain happy. I don't want to bore you too much, that's all you really need to know to get what's going on. I think? Let me know.

Point is, I want to make the rectangle that flashes colors on keypress, fade back to gray on key release. I figured I'd do this with `time`, having a list of colors, iterate through them in steps back to gray setting the rectangle's fill to each with `canvas.itemconfig` with a like 0.01-second delay after each step. But the rectangle behaves as it did before I added the flair: key-press, cyan, key-release, gray. No animation. I tried lengthening the steps to 1 second (looong, but on purpose to see if I was just missing something; the same cyan shade stuck for 4 steps' worth of time, it should have iterated), and setting the rectangle color in the final step to an ugly magenta. The magenta stuck obviously because I never bothered changing it until another keypress cyanned it again. So why aren't the shades iterating. Also, feel free to call your band The Iterating Shades.

My code, slimmed down as much as possible:

```
# Blah blah blah, setup, but here's the key release handler (The part *I think* that's messing crap up).

def key_release(e):
    if (e.char == 'q'):
        for i in ["#0088dd", "#005e99", "#002841", "#2e2e2e"]:
            canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=i)
            time.sleep(0.04)
        canvas.itemconfig(kaq, fill="gray20")
    elif (e.char == 'e'):
        for i in ["#ff9500", "#9e5d00", "#523000", "#2e2e2e"]:
            canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=i)
            time.sleep(0.04)
        canvas.itemconfig(kae, fill="gray20")
    time.sleep(0.04)
```

There. Short(?) code, and I didn't blab on too long. All's well that ends well!

Got any ideas? Fixes? Solutions? Pitchforks to throw? Let me know, with a healthy amount of thanks from me to you. I hope this glitch is just not me being silly! Have a great day! And let me know too if you need more code-- but some people are big on Minimum Reproducible Examples, so I kept it short here.

Comment: The *only* thing that `time.sleep()` accomplishes in a Tkinter program is to lock up the GUI completely.  Delays and event-driven programming don't get along very well - the proper approach is to use `.after()` to schedule the next step of your animation a little bit into the future, and then return to the mainloop.

Comment: I trust you. Let me give it a shot and close this question for now. I'll reopen it if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I guess you can't close a question with <3000 reputation. I'll quote your response in an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: Add `canvas.update_idletasks()` after `canvas.itemconfig(...)`.

Comment: Do not cannibalize your question or delete its content, if you posted it here, it is meant to stay for other people.

Comment: Understood, sorry. Will re-add as follow-up. I was a little leery about how to go about this; guessed something like this might happen. Sorry again. Edit: Accidentally undid your rollback when I was copying Revision 4's contents. Redone.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit. The answer below does not work. Sorry Jason, not your fault!!**

My new code looks like this, but does the same thing. I had to declare a global variable called `blue_step` and have the method reference it because I was having trouble figuring out how to use `.after()` with arguments ... but that's beside the point. Anyway:

```py
# ...
def cycle_blue():
    global blue_step, rect
    canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=["#0088dd", "#005e99", "#002841", "#2e2e2e"][blue_step])
# ...
def key_release(e):
    global blue_step
    blue_step = 0
    if (e.char == 'q'):
        # for i in ["#0088dd", "#005e99", "#002841", "#2e2e2e"]:
            # canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill=i)
            # time.sleep(0.04)
        for i in range(0, 3):
            canvas.after(400, cycle_blue)
            blue_step += 1
# ...
```

Any help?

---

**Previous thoughts**

According to @jasonharper:

> The only thing that `time.sleep()` accomplishes in a Tkinter program is to
> lock up the GUI completely. Delays and event-driven programming don't get
> along very well - the proper approach is to use `.after()` to schedule the
> next step of your animation a little bit into the future, and then return to
> the mainloop.

I'll try this method and update in a few days. It may not work, but I'll mark this correct until then. Thank you, @jasonharper.

Edit: I cannot mark correct for two days.